# Reference and filter data to other sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to reference data from one Excel spreadsheet to another spreadsheet and filter it? The data on the new sheet should be updated automatically.
E.g.

Sheet 1
colA|colB|colC
xxxx|1111|2222
yyyy|3333|4444
xxxx|5555|6666

filter by xxxx:

Sheet 2
colA|colB|colC
xxxx|1111|2222
xxxx|5555|6666

Sheet 2 should be automatically updated if data on Sheet 1 changes

Answer (score 10):

This works in Excel 2010:

- Insert > Pivot Table
- Add colA, colB, and colC as Row Labels
- PivotTable Design ribbon bar (Excel 2010)
- Subtotals > Do not show
- Grand Totals > Off for rows and columns
- Report Layout > Show in tabular form
- Report Layout > Repeat all item labels
- PivotTable Options > deselect the +/- buttons
- *You should now essentially have a copy of your table*
- Filter by whichever field you wish

This gets you close to what you want. You will still need to refresh the PivotTable (Ctrl + Alt + F5 to refresh all in the workbook).

Comment: This answer should be the chosen answer as it gives instructions on how to achieve end result, instead of naming a feature that will do it

Answer (score 1):

This is why pivot tables exist. It will do this automatically for you.

Comment: I got a similar problem. Can you elaborate on how to do this with pivot-tables? I've never used them.